# How to get the just-inserted record ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My table ID is an auto-increment column, I want to get the ID when I insert the record. how can I do so?

this is how I insert the record:

```
ds.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Cases (pName,sDate,pAge,sAge,dAge,sex,status)
                    VALUES ('" + pname.Text + "','" + sdate.Text + "'," + patAge.Text + "," + sage.Text + "," + dage.Text + ",'" + sex.SelectedValue + "','Draft')";

ds.Insert();
```

`ds` is an `SqlDataSource`

Comment: Site note: always use [**parametrized queries**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid SQL injection....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Using a SQLCommand:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Cases (pName,sDate,pAge,sAge,dAge,sex,status)
                    VALUES ('" + pname.Text + "','" + sdate.Text + "'," + patAge.Text + "," + sage.Text + "," + dage.Text + ",'" + sex.SelectedValue + "','Draft'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

int newRecordId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

It's also worth noting that you should parametize your queries to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: should I use the `SQLCommand` instead of the `ds.insertCommand` ?

Answer (score 8):

You can select [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) after your insert statement.

You should also consider using SQL parameters for your insert values to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Update

Since you're using a SqlDataSource, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs). Here's an abbreviated example using parameters:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ManageProductsDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NORTHWNDConnectionString %>"
    InsertCommand=
        "INSERT INTO [Products] ([ProductName], [UnitPrice], [Discontinued])
         VALUES (@ProductName, @UnitPrice, @Discontinued); SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UnitPrice" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Discontinued" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I haven't tested this, but it should be close enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: thank you for replaying,
do I have to add it in the same `insertCommand` ? .. and what do you mean by  using SQL parameters?

Comment: Thank you so much , I just want to make sure, is this working with values taking from controls?

Comment: I got it, but how can I use it in a `.aspx.cs` file ?

Comment: If you need to do this from codebehind, go with @Curt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example:

[example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304124645/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100108-1.aspx)

Comment: I took a look to it but I didn't know how to apply it